# ¿Entonces cómo obtener el json desde una consulta request.get(url)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, api

Intenté obtener utilizar el API de wikipedia sobre [este articulo](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_d%27accidents_impliquant_des_sous-marins_depuis_2000).

Sin embargo cuando utilizo :

```
url = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Liste_d%27accidents_impliquant_des_sous-marins_depuis_2000&exintro=&exsentences=2&explaintext=&redirects=&formatversion=2"
response_dict = requests.get(url)
```

Cuando hizo `response_dict.text` me da :

```
'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html class="client-nojs" lang="fr" dir="ltr">\n<head>\n<meta charset="UTF-8"/>\n<title>Résultat de l’API de MediaWiki — Wikipédia</title>\n<script>document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace( /(^|\\s)client-nojs(\\s|$)/, "$1client-js$2" );</scr ...
```

Sin embargo me gustaría obtener el array json para utilizarlo en una dataframe.

```
{
    "batchcomplete": true,
    "query": {
        "normalized": [
            {
                "fromencoded": false,
                "from": "Liste_d'accidents_impliquant_des_sous-marins_depuis_2000",
                "to": "Liste d'accidents impliquant des sous-marins depuis 2000"
            }
        ],
        "pages": [
            {
                "pageid": 8464888,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Liste d'accidents impliquant des sous-marins depuis 2000",
                "extract": "Cet article traite des principaux accidents et incidents ayant impliqué des sous-marins depuis l’an 2000."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

¿Entonces cómo obtener el json desde una consulta request.get(url) ?

Además, esta es una sub-pregunta, pero ¿cómo obtener no solamente el `title` y el `extract` en la consulta pero también el contenido del articulo? En efecto me gustaria transformar la pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En una dataframe para análisis más extenso:

```
date name                              text
2000 L'explosion du Koursk             blablabal
2001 Collision entre l'Ehime Mahru ... ...
...  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta añadir **el formato** en el que esperas recibir la respuesta: `format=json`. Tu URL quedaría así:

[url = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Liste_d%27accidents_impliquant_des_sous-marins_depuis_2000&exintro=&exsentences=2&explaintext=&redirects=&formatversion=2&format=json"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Liste_d%27accidents_impliquant_des_sous-marins_depuis_2000&exintro=&exsentences=2&explaintext=&redirects=&formatversion=2&format=json)

Comment: Oui, désolé, je n'ai pas été assez perspicace. Para los demas que buscaria [aqui los formatos que pueden utilizar](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Data_formats#Output).

Comment: Espero que no me estés llamando nada *raro* ... mira que este sábado voy a París, y se quién eres, @ThePassenger xDD

Comment: De hecho, es extremadamente extraño!

Comment: No te sigo: ¿ no obtienes el `JSON` al añadir `&format=json` ? Porque en el navegador funciona correctamente.

Comment: Si ¡Era sobre el hecho de que dijiste que me conocías!

Comment: ¡¡ jajajajaja !! No hombre, era broma. ¿ Como te voy a conocer ?  Solo conozco **tu nick**, @ThePassenger. Seguro que si pregunto por `ThePassenger` a cualquier en DisneyLand Paris sabe decirme quién eres ;-p

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90053/discussion-between-thepassenger-and-trauma).